# How to save intent and start from same position later

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent

In my application I have flow in which to complete a task user have step of 5-6 activities in which I also store data from every single activity. So I need if any user exit the flow and comes after a while user can start where he left and all the data should work same on back pressed as well.

I have idea to use local database in which I can use update the local database every time I leave an activity and update view every time comes on activity but I am looking for much simpler approach.

Comment: You can use intent's putextra and getextra methods. put your identifier string when starting intent, get it in second activity on create method. With this identifier Sting find out last saved point and go there programatically. Due to writing this from mobile, I cant show an example.

Comment: Usually, Android doesn't recommend using multiple activities. Ideally, an activity is something that needs to be revealed to outside of the scope of your application through the manifest file. Do think over whether you need to use multiple activities vis-a-vis fragments. [Single Activity: Why, When, and How](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU), because when you do, it becomes much easier to retain and manage your user flows

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi i need to come out of the flow and then after a while start from same screen.

Comment: @Aswath i complete agree with for using multiple fragment on single activity in such cases. But i am stuck in this situation where i have to deal with activities only, also this save flow feature need to be implement

Comment: @Cqlsys In that case, a quick and dirty method would be using static data class instance for each activity and storing your data just before you finish that activity and repopulate the activity with the data saved. Another way would be to use SharedPreferences and store the data in them and retrieve and repopulate the same way.

Comment: @Aswath i am also had this thing in my mind but as you already told that it's dirty method that why i was looking for some other option is possible.